# Find residue at poles of $\frac{1}{z\sin z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

$$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z\sin z}$$

At poles, the denominator is $0$, so the poles are $z=0$ and points where $\sin z=0$ i.e. $z=n\pi$

Now, to find residue at $z=0$,
I take the series expansion of $sinz$ and proceed as follows:

$$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z\sin z}= \dfrac{1}{z(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots)} = \dfrac{1}{z^2(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\cdots)}
= \dfrac {[1-(\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}+\cdots)]^{-1}}{z^2}$$

Expanding the numerator by binomial theorem and simplifying, we get:

$$\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{1}{3!}-\dfrac{z^2}{5!}+\cdots$$

Hence we see the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is $0$ and so the residue at $z=0$ is $0$.

Is this approach correct?

If yes, how do I find residue at $z=n\pi$? I do not need the complete working out, I just need hints. Thanks!

Comment: I've just edited to make use of some more of the MathJax formatting. I didn't change any of the details of the question, however. Hopefully this is helpful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z\sin(z)}$ has a double pole at the origin with residue zero, since $f(z)$ is an even function.
The other poles occur at (non-zero) integer multiples of $\pi$ and they are simple poles, hence

$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z\sin(z)},z=k\pi\right) = \lim_{z\to k\pi}\frac{z-k\pi}{z\sin(z)} = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{(z+k\pi)\sin(z+k\pi)} \\= (-1)^k \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{(z+k\pi)\sin(z)}=\color{red}{\frac{(-1)^k}{k\pi}}.$$

Comment: I understand everything here except this- how does $f(z)$ have a double pole at z=0? Is it because $z=0$ and $sinz=0$ also gives $z=0$ as one of its possible solutions?

Comment: @Diya: $z=0$ is a simple pole for both $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$, hence it is a double pole for $f(z)$.